# In Black Clover, how is Nero able to find the magic stones?

Tags: black-clover

I have been watching *Black Clover* from the start and was interested in the bird (which later became his pet name Nero) from the start and followed him on his head from the time he joined the Black Bulls squad. I knew they said in the start of episodes that these type of birds stick to a person having low mana.

The bird Nero, seems to be able to point important things to Asta, like finding him the magic stone in an underwater temple and mostly helping him point to something important. My hypothesis is that he could have some sort of mystical powers to maybe.

How is the bird (Nero) able to point out important things to Asta?

Answer (score 3):

Your hypothesis is in the right direction, though the powers don't seem to be very mystical, just unusual in his species.

Nero is of the species known as [Anti-Birds](http://blackclover.wikia.com/wiki/Anti-bird) which the wikia describes as:

> Anti-birds are small birds that have black feathers on their back, wings, and around their face. Their faces have red feathers while their undersides have white feathers. Their beaks are black and they have a pair of feather that are shaped like downturned horns.
>
> The Anti-birds are **capable of sensing mana** and will peck at those with low or no mana. Anti-birds will not approach anyone with high levels of mana and will become frightened when they get close to those with powerful mana

(emphasis mine)

The wikia entry for [Nero](http://blackclover.wikia.com/wiki/Nero) lists this mana sensory ability as what allows him to detect magical items and and help them navigate toward a source of mana. This utilization of the mana detection seems to be unique to him, as the wikia also mentions the following ways in which Nero differs from usual anti-birds:

> 1. Nero is the only Anti-bird that has upturned horns and two tail feathers shaped like arrows
> 2. Currently only Nero is shown to be able to detect magic stones and Anti Magic weapons

As you can see, there's no clear confirmation or reason *why* Nero is different than the others, but we do know that he is the only one who can do this.

Comment: so then I guess we should have to wait and see if our hypothesis is right. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Nero is a complete mystery. I believe he appeared in the second chapter hidden among all the anti-mana birds. He sometimes disappears so you need to keep an eye on him and where he heads to, its a mini game I'd like to call "Find Nero". In the previous arc he found Noelle who was stalking Asta and stayed with her at Rebecca's house, so he was never seen by Licht who might have known his secrets or his past. I'm pretty confident that Nero has a connection to Asta's grimoire and Licht's master here is my theory/speculation or what ever you'd like to call it.

Nero is defiantly not a normal bird and he seems like he knows the secrets of the stones. I think he is supposed to be a swallow so I searched swallows and found two interesting points. According to a site about tattoos in Greek and Roman mythology gods were able to change their form into a swallow and in Japan swallows represent unfaithfulness. I don't know if any of this is true or even relevant but it could support the idea of Nero being Licht's master. The people that were loved by mana were compared to gods and assuming Licht's master is just like Licht one of them, then we could also assume that he has a grudge against Clover for murdering his people so he could be Asta's enemy. Even though it would be a cool twist I don't believe Tabata would be allowed to make the story's mascot the possible end game villain. I think Nero is Licht's master's maybe magical pet and I think he'll be Asta's pet until the end. In Asta's earliest design you could see Nero with him and Asta's hair is designed as a nest for Nero. I think other than the possible importance of his past Nero's role other than be an extremely badass f*cking bird is transportation. Asta has 0 mana so he can't use a broom and he can't always depend on Finral's portal forever, so what if Nero's size could be changed or be controlled not only will he be a sick flying mount but he'll also be able to repay Asta for all the free rides he's been nicking.

`Source - https://www.reddit.com/r/BlackClover/comments/4o0rip/so_whats_up_with_the_bird/`

Answer (score 0):

Actually Nero's real name is Secre. She was the servant of Lumiere. Lumiere was the first wizard king. Secre sealed Lumiere in stone on top that demon's head. I forgot why she sealed Lumiere though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen the latest episode 103, you will notice Nero sitting a top of the church UNTIL Asta gets Licht's sword. Then he lands on his head. I think Nero is his spirit. I also think that Nero will be apart of him in more ways than one. I think he will be a ride, a fighting support and something totally different in the end. I have so many theories in my head now, I do know which direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, In the latest episode we learn that Nero is 500 years old.. That's around the time of the first wizard king and the fall of the elves.. I believe that Nero played a part in hiding the magic stones after what happened with the elves, just in case something like that happened again! I tried my best not to spoil anything, you find out everything that happened in the past in episode 181!

Answer (score 0):

Nero is a bird who senses magic but is also a human sealed away possibly has part of all the magic stones mana within her but nit to be told from where I stand.

Answer (score -1):

I think that Nero is the spirit just as sylph spirit Yuno has. Nero is the spirit of the demon that dwells inside Asta. If u watch the 3 episode you can see him when Asta is training in forest. He was with Asta since he got the grimoire.